# Learning resources and tutorials for using the Java Batik Library

Tags: java, batik

I am using the Batik library, which is very useful to display SVG graphics in Java.  For the basic use case of displaying and rendering an SVG document is quite simple to use.  However, I want to do some other advanced graphic manipulation and I am struggling as I don't find any good resource that will allow me to perform the following types of task:

- Detecting the component under the mouse
- Getting a component by id and changing the color used to render
- Manipulate components
- Adding new components
- Detecting mouse clicks on components

Is there any good resource or tips to use this library that you know about?

Answer (score 5):

You might like to read through the [slides of a tutorial session on using Batik](http://mcc.id.au/2007/09/batik-course/) that I presented at SVG Open a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth looking at [Java™ Drawing with Apache Batik: A Tutorial](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0975212893). The contents list looks pretty comprehensive.

I wrote an SVG display ages ago which used Batik and handled mouse events / colour changes. IIRC I had to make the changes to the SVG via the DOM interface since Batik didn't support that at all. Things may have changed now, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the [W3C Doc on SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/)?

It seems to list how to do most things; particularly look at Appendix A: DOM Enhancemenets, and if not in here, you can check the previous versions of the doc.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, at least reading through the spec will help me sleep better at night :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will also helpful

http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/

Comment: Not really, I am writing a java application.  svgweb is a renderer for a web browser.