# How to set a transparent Icon from a transparent SVG file

Tags: java, svg, icons, jlabel, batik

I have a transparent SVG file.
I would like to use it as the icon of a JLabel, via setIcon().

I use Batik for SVG, but I don't know how to do this.
Can you help me ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution :

```
SVG r = new SVG(new File(*something*).toURI().toString());
BufferedImage img = r.createBufferedImage();
this.enabledIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
label.setIcon(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you take a look at Batik project

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/

It's a library for use SVG images in Java apps.

And this question have some help about using Batik library
[Learning resources and tutorials for using the Java Batik Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558852/learning-resources-and-tutorials-for-using-the-java-batik-library)